# Minify HTML Code used by AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In my application, I want to minify not only my javascript code but also html templates in a single javascript file. But I cannot find any examples how to do this.

```
templates/tmpl1.html
templates/tmpl2.html
controllers/ctrl1.js
controllers/ctrl2.js

-> minify all files to "app.js"
```

I think HTML code should be converted to strings, because as I know, it's not possible to write HTML into javascript files.

Comment: If you use grunt there's angular-templates doing exactly this. (https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-angular-templates)

Comment: Well I don't see much interest minifying HTML, and even less putting it in a js file especially if it is to be consumed directly by a browser that won't handle a js file the same way as an HTML one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular has a [template cache](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24templateCache) that you can directly tamper with.
So you can

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.run(function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('templates/tmpl2.html', '<strong>This is the content of the template</strong>');
});
```

You can either manually create a .js file that adds all your templates in `$templateCache` as strings and then combine/minify it together with all your other .js files, or you could (**should**) use [node.js](http://nodejs.org/), [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) and [grunt-angular-templates](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-angular-templates) and handle all of this automatically.